# Fatal error: Class 'mPDF' not found in myproject/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/Pdf.php on line 281

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I have used kartik pdf extension to print my report in pdf format.Things are going well in my local computer but when i put my codes in server error appears like this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mPDF' not found in myproject/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/Pdf.php on line 281
```

In server i have uploaded yii2-mpdf folder inside kartik-v folder and also mpdf folder.
My code of controller for pdf print:

```
 use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
 public function actionPearlFinancialReport()
{
$pdf = new Pdf([

        //'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,

        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,

        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,

        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,

        'content' =>  $this->renderPartial('_financial_report', ['model' => $model,'parameter'=>$parameter]), 
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'cssInline'=> '.kv-heading-1{font-size:15px;text-align:center;}',
        'options' => ['title' => 'Pearl Financial Report'],
         'methods' => [
            'SetHeader'=>['Pearl Financial Report'],
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);

    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

}

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to register this extension with composer:

For example my work directory is c:\xampp\htdocs\my-project

In a command prompt -> cd c:\xampp\htdocs\my-project

And register with this command:

C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project>php c:\xampp\htdocs\composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-mpdf "dev-master"

I always register kartik's extensions with this metod, I hope want to be useful for you too.